# Calling GeoCode function from two Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm very new to this and trying to run the GeoCode function and call it from two different DIV IDs. It works fine with the first div (Where I'm calling it from US States drop-down list) but not with the second (Canada States drop-down list). Please help me with that.

Here is my HTML:

```
<select class="address" value="Geocode" onchange="codeAddress(this)">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="Alabama,AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska,AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="Arizona,AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="Arkansas,AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="California,CA">California</option>
    <option value="Colorado,CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="Connecticut,CT">Connecticut</option>
</select>
<select class="address" value="Geocode" onchange="codeAddress(this)">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="Alberta,AB">Alberta</option>
    <option value="British Columbia,BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="Manitoba,MB">Manitoba</option>
    <option value="New Brunswick,NB">New Brunswick</option>
    <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador,NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
</select>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42, -99);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Your Geo-Location',
                maxWidth: 200
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 5,
                },
                draggable: true,
                map: map
            });

            //Uncomment the function below if you want to change the center to the user's location
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function () {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }
}
$('.address').change(function () {

codeAddress($(this).val());
 });
function codeAddress(address) {
    var address = document.getElementByClassName('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(7);
            //This is the variable thats let us display the icon on the selected location from the drop-down
            // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            //map: map,
            //position: results[0].geometry.location
            //});
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Before editing your code, I noticed that one line of code with strange quotes: `<option value=”Arizona,AZ">Arizona</option>`. Make sure you are using standard quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have 2 different HTML elements with the same id.

You can base your script on a class instead of the select id:

```
<select class="address" value="Geocode">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="Alabama,AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska,AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

<select class="address" value="Geocode">
    <option>Select 2</option>
    <option value="Alberta,AB">Alberta</option>
    <option value="British Columbia,BC">British Columbia</option>
</select>
```

Then simply add a change event listener on your 2 select elements with class *address* and send the value to your `codeAddress` function:

```
$('.address').change(function () {

    codeAddress($(this).val());
});

function codeAddress(address) {

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(7);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Wrap your jQuery code in a `$(document).ready()` function.
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
$(function () {
    $('.address').change(function () {

        codeAddress($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried the code but looks like I'm still making some mistake. Can you please help me track, where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: What's not working? Did you add the classes as in my example? Did you modify your code accordingly?

Comment: Yup, I updated the code. Please see with the question.

Comment: I still don't know what is not working. Make sure the change event handler is in your document ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for example: `$(function() { //place it here! });`

Comment: I still can't figure out, here is the link http://jsbin.com/bubop/1/edit?html,output

Comment: See my **edited** answer. I gave you HTML and JS code in my answer and comment but you didn't use it. It is different than what you have. Try again.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right and the code works now. It took me sometime to do it correctly. All I can say, I'm at a very beginner level. :)

Comment: One single character can make your whole script work or not. Make sure you always try what is proposed to you, unless it has obvious mistakes in it. In which case you should let the person who answered to your question know about it. Glad you got it working.